# SWRevealController Hanging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

When I segue from a rear menu cell via `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` to a `UITableViewController`, the animation starts quickly but then hangs without app crashing, UI is unaccessible via touches and doesn't react anymore. When instead I use a `UIViewController` it works perfectly. As soon as I add again a `UITableView` in the `UIViewController`, it hangs again.

Basically, when using with an `UIViewController` it works. When using either with `UITableViewController` or nested `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` it hangs.

Any Help?
Vince

Comment: FYI, this is not a direct answer to your question, but I managed to go to a UITableViewController with a UINavigationController embedded. It would be better if you share some of the crash reports.

Comment: As mentioned, it doesn't crash, the UI just hangs after a fraction of a second after the animation started. If I use the sample project and add a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController it works as well, but just not in my project